# What is an acceptable response to "wie geht's"?

Tags: salutation

If someone asks me how something is or how I am doing, for example if someone asks me "wie geht's?" Is it okay to respond with "alles gut" or should I say "Alles ist gut?"

Comment: `Gut, danke.` Or if you want to be nice and return the question, `Gut, danke, und Dir/und selbst?`. Note however that someone asking you `Wie geht's?` is almost certainly asking about you, not about how *something* is going. To ask you how your work is coming along, someone would ask `(Wie) kommst du voran?` or possibly `Geht's voran?`.

Comment: informal: _Läuft!_, _Muss ja!_

Comment: In meinem Freundeskreis hört man oft diesen mittlerweile ritualisierten Begrüßungsdialog (Wiener Dialekt): »Servus, wie geht's?« - »Jo, eh. Und dir?« - »Jo, eh a ›jo eh‹«. Hochdeutsche Übersetzung: »Servus, wie geht es dir?« - »Nun ja, einigermaßen. Und dir?« - »Naja, ebenso auch ›nun ja, einigermaßen‹«. - Man sollte ergänzen, dass »Jo, eh« sehr viel mehr Bedeutungen hat, z.B.: https://www.facebook.com/hubert.schoelnast/posts/10203556292417617

Comment: I always answer "auf zwei Beinen wie eine Ente, aber nicht so schwabbelig" "

Answer (score 15):

Doesn't really matter, there are several options and as those are short, daily phrases, no one expects you to form out lengthy sentences. However, it is common to thank and to ask how the other person is doing:

> Danke, gut, und Ihnen? (more formal)
>
> Danke, gut, und selbst? (less formal)

Just observe what other people say, as there are regional customs.

Comment: I'm a German living abroad, but at the German school of Rome and in Saarbrücken, where I lived for 1 year, I never happened to hear "Danke, gut, und _selbst_?" instead of "Danke, gut, und _dir_?". Moreover, this _selbst_ is not grammatically correct, as far as I know.

Comment: I'd like to second @WalterTross. _"Wie geht's?"_ is short for _"Wie geht es Dir/Ihnen?"_ rather than for _"Wie geht es?"_ (there is no third _Es_ involved in this communication)

Comment: @WalterTross: As I said, there are regional customs, and it is quite common here in the south. When talking about phrases, I'd say that grammar is not as important; they tend to develop a life of their own, being changed to be spoken quick, easy and harmonical.

Answer (score 2):

Gut

maybe "Schlecht", but short as "Gut" is the common answer

Answer (score 0):

I thought about these possibilities:

> - mir geht’s gut, danke!
> - mir geht’s so-und-so, und dir?
> - mir geht’s schlecht, und dir?
> - mir geht’s prima, danke!

But I am not a native speaker! I hope these are ok.

Comment: I'm austrian, not german. But I would never use `mir geht's schlecht`, except with very close friends.

Comment: @raznagul: Maybe a better phrase is mir geht’s nicht-so-gut,

Comment: @TomAu: No. What I meant with the comment was: Even if I don't feel well I usually wouldn't tell other people. "Wie geht's?" is usually just meant as polite salutation, and not an actual concern about the other persons condition.

Answer (score 0):

You say "Gut". And to ask them back you have to say "und dir?". Some say "und Ihnen?". It is dependent on how you want to respond. “Und ihnen” is used when talking to someone who is not a close friend or family member, as it is the polite form of “you”.

Answer (score 0):

**Gut:**

- Mir geht es sehr gut.
- Mir geht es spitze.
- Prima.

**So So:**

- Na ja, es geht.
- Es läuft.
- Es geht so.

**Schlecht:**

- Mir geht es nicht gut.
- Nicht so gut.
- Schlecht drauf.

For asking back: Und Dir, Und Ihnen, Bei Dir, Bei Ihnen...